# Regular expression in Delphi

Tags: regex, pcre

I have this regular expression to check for timestamps in HH:MM:SS format:

```
(20|21|22|23|[01]\d|\d)(([:][0-5]\d){1,2})
```

but I would like to disregard timestamps that is preceded with "run time = "

```
00:01:02 -> YES
compile time = 00:01:02 -> YES (only 00:01:02)
run time = 00:01:02 -> NO
```

Can this be done using regular expression?

Comment: I've removed the Delphi tag (as your question has nothing to do with Delphi), and replaced it with the PCRE tag (the type of regular expression parser you're using). The question is simply about regular expressions, not about Delphi.

Comment: Is your timestamp always in the form of HH:MM:SS? Because that regex optionally matches only 1 digit for each section, and allows for the last part (the :SS) to be missing completely. This regex would strictly follow that pattern: `(?:2[0-3]|[10]\d):[0-5]\d:[0-5]\d`

Answer (score 0):

A `negative Lookahead` will do it:

```
^(?!run time = ).*?(20|21|22|23|[01]\\d|\\d)(([:][0-5]\\d){1,2})
```

http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Answer (score 0):

Combine negative lookahead as suggested by Tuga with correct parsing of HH:MM:SS as suggested by CAustin and add a capture group so that you can extract just the HH:MM:SS part:

```
(?!run time = ).*?((?:2[0-4]|[10]\d):[0-5]\d:[0-5]\d)
```

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to disregard timestamps that is preceded with "run time = "

To truly fulfill this requirement, we need a *negative lookbehind*, which PCREs do provide.

```
(?<!run time = )(([01]\d|2[0-3])(:[0-5]\d){2})
```